# How to use Material Design Lite to target only desktop browser

Tags: material-design-lite

I'm using MDL for a desktop-only web application and I do not need the content to be responsive. That is, even if the user resizes the browser window, I don't need to re-arrange the content. Neither it will ever be browsed on a mobile device. How do I prevent the content from being responsive?

Comment: Add a fixed width to your main element e.g. body or form

Comment: Adding a fixed width to the body element didn't solve the problem..

Comment: That depends of you content. If there are children with position="absolute"  you may set the width for those. E.g with only `div.mdl-gird` in body setting width on body should do. If you use `mdl-layout` There will be an `div.mdl-layout__container` with `position: absolute`. Then you need to set the with for this.  But any way your question if far to open. You need to add  your current code etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://getmdl.io/components/index.html#layout-section/grid

I have provided reference to the MDL grid at the above link.

The content should not be responsive without initiating something like the mdl-grid class and mdl-cell class which would then allow you to label pieces like a content card with specific sizing, which will resize based on the device.  If you are using your own style sheets you could create a card class which would have a specific pixel width you believe would work best for the project on a desktop.